# Can one of these two posts get re-opened?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow

Exhibit A: [Need a good Internet Explorer 6, 7, 8 standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065989/need-a-good-internet-explorer-6-7-8-standalone)

Exhibit B: [Running Internet Explorer 6, Internet Explorer 7, and Internet Explorer 8 on the same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463/running-internet-explorer-6-internet-explorer-7-and-internet-explorer-8-on-the)

A is closed as a dupe of B, and B is closed as a dupe of A. (did we just divide by zero here?) Should one of these two get re-opened?

Comment: I have re-opened [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463/running-internet-explorer-6-internet-explorer-7-and-internet-explorer-8-on-the). Holy recursion Batman!

Comment: the review queues are causing a lot of this. I see questions where "Duplicate 1" is already closed as a dupe about 1/5th of the time. Sometimes of something else, more rarely of the current candidate for closing. Unfortunately adding a comment about it is hard from the review queue. I vote DNC but I guess others don't.

Comment: Why aren't they both closed as off topic?  :P  This is a software/installation thing, not a programming thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, recursive duplicates do happen. They are somewhat rare, but they do happen.

Exhibit B has been re-opened. It might be closed again for different reasons, but the recursive closure is fixed.

Comment: Slightly OT question: I have once written a detailled guide posted on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/q/10541225) which explains how to set up a single machine containing the major browsers, including IE6/7/8 (extended to 9 and 10 once IE10 is launched). Since this information might be very interesting to those Googlers who arrive at this popular question (Exh. B), what would be the best way to bring it up on question Exhibit B?

Comment: I thought recursive duplicates were prevented by the system now? It's gives you some extremely poorly written error message about "only leading in a circle"

Comment: @BenBrocka In the mod dash, they are .. in fact I have seen the system tell me closing would result in a circular loop. The fact that these two questions ended up in such a state sort of hints that logic is lacking in review. I can't be sure, though. I've only seen this happen half a dozen times .. could also just be timing?